# Detail-table has detail-table

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am a student of a university, and my teacher thinks my ERD is weird.

ERD is about ramen restaurant.

The order receipt looks like this:

1. Tofu Ramen         $3
   Topping:

   - Meatball        $1
   - Kerupuk         $1
2. Tofu Ramen         $3
   Topping: none

Then this is my ERD:

[image: my ERD]

*ISA is the generalization.

Then this is a schema release.

[image: skema relasi]
*pelayan entity is changed to akun

Can you spot my mistake?

*Note:
- ditambahi = add with.
- memiliki = has.
- pelayan = waiter.

Comment: The second one looks like a schematic diagram to me.

Comment: someone edited the post, he tell me the term is schema release.